# How to return object from function?

Tags: javascript

I am having conceptual Javascript issues while returning Object from functions. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong here?

```
var productsPartsObj = {
  layers: ['toe', 'base', 'shaft'],
  layer: [
    {
      name: 'toe',
      height: 75,
      width: 78,
      coords: {
        x: 20,
        y: 120
      }
    }
  ]
}

var coords = {};
coords = (function() {
  productsPartsObj.layer.forEach(function(layerObj){
    if ( layerObj.name === "toe" ) {
      return layerObj.coords;
    }
  })
})()

console.log(coords); //logs undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning from the `forEach` callback, not from the immediately-executed function expression. You could do this instead (assuming you know there will only ever be one element of the `layer` array with a `name` matching the value in question:

```
var coords = (function() {
  return productsPartsObj.layer.filter(function(layerObj){
      return layerObj.name === "toe";
  })[0].coords;
})();
```

Notice that there are 2 `return` statements - the first one returns from the IIFE, and the second returns from the `filter` callback.

Also notice that I've moved the `var` keyword into this statement. There is no point assigning an empty object to `coords` and then simply overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous function is not returning any value.

```
var productsPartsObj = {
    layers : ['toe', 'base', 'shaft'],
    layer : [{
                name : 'toe',
                height : 75,
                width : 78,
                coords : {
                    x : 20,
                    y : 120
                }
            }]
}

var coords = {};
coords = (function() {
    var x;
    productsPartsObj.layer.forEach(function(layerObj) {
                if (layerObj.name === "toe") {
                    x = layerObj.coords;
                }
            })
    return x;
})()

console.log(coords);
```

Else set the coords value directly using

```
var coords = {};
(function() {
    productsPartsObj.layer.forEach(function(layerObj) {
                if (layerObj.name === "toe") {
                    coords = layerObj.coords;
                }
            })
})()
```